# WebStorm annotate cutting off usernames on dashes and spaces

Tags: git, annotations, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When using the `Annotate` functionality in WebStorm, if a user that commited code has a username that contains a space or dash, WebStorm only shows the part of their name after the space or dash.

I'm not sure if this is intentional functionality, or if there is an option to change it (I couldn't find one).  But I would expect it to behave like `git blame` by default.

Currently:

- "user-name" -> "name" shows
- "firstName lastName" -> "lastName" shows

Expected:

- "user-name" -> "user-name"
- "firstName lastName" -> "firstName lastName"

**Question:** is there an option to switch the functionality? or is it a bug or expected behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yup, right click the annotation bar > view > name > full name:[image]